# Could not get the values from an Ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I made a a constructor for an object in Javascript. I would like this object to be able to send some data to the server.

```
function basket(list_of_things, price, basket_name){
      this.list_of_things = list_of_things;
      this.price = price;
      this.basket_name = basket_name;
      this.share = function(){
        $.post('/post_basket',
        {
          basket_name: this.basket_name,
          list_of_things: this.list_of_things
        },
        function(data,status){
          alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
        };
        };
```

I have also made a route in my Python function

```
@app.route('/post_basket', methods=['POST'])
def post_basket():
    a = request.args.get('basket_name', type = str)
    print a
    return ("poo")
```

I would like to get the data from the Ajax post and it kept returning None to me. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/post_basket',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {basketName: this.basket_name, listOfThings: this.list_of_things},
   success: function(response){
      alert("Data: " + response);
   },

   error: function(e) {
     alert(e)
   }

)}
```

I dont think you need to wrap your ajax call in a function here. It would also be helpful to have an error function so we could get more info on why it is failing. Perhaps the route is wrong, maybe you need the full route, or you are getting a 400 for a bad request. What I wrote above is more traditional ajax, maybe it will give you some things to try out. Let us know if you have an error message for us :)

Comment: I used your code and it is still a success, like before, the only problem is now that it said that .share is not a function and on the backend, I am still getting nothing, despite my python code successfully returning poo back to the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, because I used post, I can access the data sent to the server by using form, not get, like below

```
@app.route('/post_basket', methods=['POST'])
  def post_basket():
    a = request.form['basket_name']
    print a
    return ("poo")
```